# Baking indirect illumination from emissive material to texture (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, emission

I make models for video games, and bake most of the details to textures that are used in a separate engine (Unreal, Unity, etc). I've tried out baking in Blender, and while stuff like normal maps and ao works fine, I have an issue with the emit bake type. When baking a map from an object that has a material with an emission (simply set to white in this example), resulting map only has the silhouette of the object, but it doesn't have any indirect illumination from it on adjacent objects.
Normally I use Vray in 3ds Max to bake out this sort of lightmap from a highpoly to lowpoly. It greatly improves the look of assets with small lights that would be too expensive to do in-engine. So it would be great if Blender's Cycles could achieve the same result. Is it possible and I'm missing some settings, or this functionality is not supported?

Screenshots for clarity. Some test objects are projected to a plane. The small box has a simple BSDF material with emission. When rendered with Emit bake type, only the silhouette is baked. Third screenshot is the desired result - rendered using Vray in 3ds Max for illustration purposes.

[image: Highpoly objects - small box has a basic emissive material applied.]
[image: Rendered to plane normal map + emit, only the outline of the object was baked, no glow]
[image: Same, but emissive map is baked in Vray in 3ds Max - glow present.]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? The best I could do was to bake from actual lights but it's not the same

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still forced to use Vray in 3ds Max for this. I'd try Vray in Blender, but they never did release a version of 2.8.
It's a very specific use case, I can understand why it's overlooked by the devs.